# ChartJs Bubble chart cut off on hover

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I'm using `"chart.js": "^4.3.2"` and I created one bubble chart but problem is when I hover bubble it gets cut off.

[image]

```
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            usePointStyle: true,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(17, 24, 39, 1)',
            bodyColor: 'rgba(209, 213, 219, 1)',
            callbacks: {
                labelPointStyle: function () {
                    return {
                        pointStyle: 'line' as PointStyle,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        rotation: 90,
                    };
                },
                title: function () {
                    return '';
                },
                label: function (tooltipItems: TooltipItem<'bubble'>) {
                    return `${tooltipItems.label} ${tooltipItems.formattedValue}%`;
                },
            },
        },
        bubbleLabel: true,
    },
    scales: {
        y: {
            // display: false,xw
        },
        x: {
            // display: false,
        },
    },
};

return (
    <>
        <canvas
            ref={chartContainer}
            className='hidden w-full h-full'
        />
        {chartData && (
            <Bubble
                data={chartData}
                options={options}
                plugins={[bubbleLabelPlugin]}
            />
        )}
    </>
);
```

}

Is there any option that I'm missing and can solve this problem?
I tried adding layout padding option but it's not working.
One option is to disable effects full but I want to have tooltip on hover.

Comment: When hovered, each bubble inflates by an amount specified
by the option [`hoverRadius`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html#interactions),
default value 4; this effect is not taken into account when allocating space for
bubbles that extend outside the chart area. A quick solution is to set `hoverRadius: 0` in `options` (check out the [namespaces](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html#dataset-properties) for possible placements of the property). A negative value for `hoverRadius` also appears to be working.